# Deformation theory of stacks and the tangent complex

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, stacks

On a smooth stack X one can construct the two-term tangent complex $T_X \in D(X)$, as in Sam Raskin's notes ([https://people.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Sept22(Dmodstack1).pdf](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Sept22(Dmodstack1).pdf)).

I would like to request references that relate $T_X$ to the deformation theory of $X$. In particular, I would expect some relation between $T_X$ and the dual numbers $K[x] / x^2$.

The following is the kind of question I am looking to solve. Consider two possible definitions of the tangent stack $TX$ as categories fibered in groupoids, where we write X(S) for the families over a scheme $S$.

$$
T_1X(S) = X(S \times Spec(K[x] / x^2))
$$

$$ 
T_2X(S) = \{(a,\sigma) \: \: s.t. \: \: a \in X(S), \sigma \in \Gamma((T_X |_S)\} 
$$

I would expect deformation theory to tell us that $T_1X = T_2X$, so that both are definitions of the tangent stack. This would emulate the deformation theory of schemes, which relates the tangent sheaf to the dual numbers. Are my expectations correct?

Edit: Thank you to Jon Pridham for pointing out some errors in the previous version of the question.

Comment: Your definition of $T_2^*$ looks more like a tangent stack than a cotangent stack. Just taking $H^0$ is too crude, though, because the functor is groupoid-valued and $H^{-1}$ will contribute to morphisms.

Comment: Thanks for these points! On your first point, since in scheme theory we use the dual sheaf $F^{\vee}$ to construct the total space $tot(F)$, I would expect to use the tangent complex to build the cotangent stack, but this could be naive. I will digest your second point!

Comment: Regarding the first point, contravariance comes in when looking at rings of functions, but not functors of points.

Comment: Absolutely true, thank you for pointing this out!